# Number of permutations for n elements with exactly 3 cycles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know how to find number of permutations with cycle. 
And I'm not sure, but for 2 it should be something like this

$\sum_{k=1}^{n=1} \binom{n}{k} (k-1)!(n-k-1)! $

But I have a problem with 3 cycles. And is there exist any general formula for number of permutations for n elements with k cycles?

Comment: Look for Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).